# Prove that $A - (B \cap C) = (A - B) \cup (A - C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $A - (B \cap C) = (A - B) \cup (A - C)$

How do I go about solving this proof? I've tried a few things but I'm stuck. I don't need the exact proof step by step, just a few hints on how to solve it would really help me.

**edit:** I tried to solve considering $3$ cases.

If $x$ is an element of $A−(B\cap C)$, then $x$ belongs to $A$ and $x$ doesn't belong to $B\cap C$.

Then, there I considered $3$ possibilites:

- $x\in A$ and ($x\in B$ or $x\in C$)
- $x\in A$ and ($x\notin B$ or $x\in C$)
- $x\in A$ and ($x\in B$ or $x\notin C$)

After that I found that all of these cases satisfied the definition of set difference which states that $A-B$ is equal to the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$. In that case my $B$ is "($B\cap C$)". After that I tried to prove the other side "$(A−B)\cup (A−C)$" but I got lost and didn't know what to do.

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Many instructors, I included, don't accept Venn diagrams as a "proof". They can give us good intuition, but they can also be wrong in some situations.

Comment: Can you show us the steps you did try?

Comment: @N.S. I quote: "I don't need the exact proof step by step, just a few hints on how to solve it would really help me." The result falls out of an appropriate Venn diagram.

Comment: @N.S. "Venn diagrams ... can also be wrong in some situations" Which situations do you have in mind?

Comment: @Did First, I highly doubt that any student can draw the correct Venn diagram for 4 or more sets. Secondly, when people draw the Venn diagrams, the picture suggests that each region is non-empty. So the picture is at least misleading (I would call it wrong) in the situation when one of the regions in the diagram is the emptyset (this includes the following cases : $A \subseteq B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \backslash B \subset C$ and $A=\emptyset$ and so on). If my students want  to use Venn diagrams, I expect them to draw the correct Venn Diagram for each possible scenario.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You may have noticed that your post was at first closed (for lack of context and effort shown), and then re-opened (after you added your attempt), and then closed as duplicate. If you post more questions next time, [do remember to include context and your thoughts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959), and it will not be closed for the first reason. Also, if you are unsatisfied with the answers to the duplicate, you can edit your question to link to the duplicate and specify what you do not understand about it, and then vote to re-open your question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A, B, C$ be sets and $x \in A \setminus (B \cap C)$.

$x \in A \setminus (B \cap C)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin (B \cap C)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge (x \notin B \vee x \notin C)$

$\Leftrightarrow (x \in A \wedge x \notin B) \vee (x \in A \wedge x \notin C)$

$\Leftrightarrow x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$.

The equivalencies give us that the LHS and the RHS are subsets of each other, so they are equal.

Comment: This site is not a homework completion site.  Please don't attract users who only want us to do their homework, by rewarding them, so they come back and again, ask homework questions.

Comment: I started the proof like you but then I considered 3 cases:

x∈A∧(x∉B∨x∉C) or x∈A∧(x∉B∨x∈C) or x∈A∧(x∈B∨x∉C) 

then I concluded that for these cases indeed x∈A∖(B∩C). But then after that I didn't know what to do. Is it necessary to consider these 3 cases or I just created more work for myself?

Comment: You created more work because $\vee$ includes your two additional cases.

Comment: I see now, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** To prove an equality of sets $X =Y$ you need to show that $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$, where $X,Y$ are the expressions in that particular problem.

**Hint 2** To show that $X \subseteq Y$ you start with "Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary." You explain what this means and try to get that $x \in Y$.

Comment: Now I see I was all around the place with my way of solving. This will also help me solve other similar proofs. Just a question though, when you say "explain what this means" should I follow a particular strategy? If so, which one? Because I tried to explain what x meant but I got really lost and ended up getting nowhere close to proofing that x also belonged to Y.

Comment: @Sara In this case when you start with $x \in A-(B \cup C)$ for example, by explain I mean you write the definition of the operation(s) you have: $x \in A - (B \cap C)$ means $x \in A$ AND $x \notin (B \cap C)$. For the last, again you explain the definition of $B \cap C$ to get that $x \notin B \cap C$ means $x \notin B$ Or $x \notin C$. This way, you explained $x \in A -(B \cap C)$ in terms of $x$ belonging/not belonging to each set. At this point, look at your goal and try to get there. This is almost every time the strategy.